# MQ 5.7 & IBM jre8 , equivalant cipher suite for cipher spec "TRIPLE_DES_SHA_US"

Tags: java, ibm-mq, ibm-jvm

I m trying to connect MQ7.5 using IBM JRE-8  over SSL . In MQ system they configured **TRIPLE_DES_SHA_US** and we are using **SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA** cipher suite in my java program to connect MQ. 
But it is giving below given error.

```
    MQJE001: An MQException occurred: Completion Code 2, Reason 2009

    MQJE016: MQ queue manager closed channel immediately during connect

    Closure reason = 2009
```

Steps i have followed 
Certificated imported to truststore 
executed java program with actual channel details of MQ.

Certificate Import to truststore:

```
    /opt/ibm/java-i386-80/jre/bin/keytool -import -alias jre_cert -file qms1.arm -keystore /opt/ibm/java-i386-80/jre/lib/security/cacerts
    Enter keystore password:
    Owner: CN="XXX, O=XXX, OU=XXX, C=IN"
    Issuer: CN="XXX, O=XXX, OU=XXX, C=IN"
    Serial number: 115d214a64b03f04
    Valid from: 1/17/17 12:36 PM until: 1/13/18 12:36 PM
    Certificate fingerprints:
         MD5:  1B:F1:6D:D1:88:5B:69:C0:B1:21:07:9C:FA:89:EC:2C
         SHA1: 77:DE:4A:66:72:77:34:CC:67:D1:3B:46:D5:1D:E3:B0:20:70:0E:5B
         SHA256: DE:F6:1C:96:4A:DE:9F:0C:AF:BF:73:52:1F:23:1A:49:E1:84:AE:3D:FD:97:0D:CF:FF:F3:C3:C7:D4:C0:9B:2E
         Signature algorithm name: SHA1withRSA
         Version: 3
    Trust this certificate? [no]:  yes
    Certificate was added to keystore
```

Sample Program we are using.

```
import com.ibm.mq.MQEnvironment;
import com.ibm.mq.MQQueueManager;
import com.ibm.mq.MQC;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLContext;
import java.security.KeyStore;
import javax.net.ssl.KeyManagerFactory;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory;
import javax.net.ssl.TrustManagerFactory;
import java.security.cert.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
public class MQTest {
    private static MQQueueManager _queueManager = null;
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    MQEnvironment.hostname = "XX.XX.XX.XX";
    MQEnvironment.channel = "CHANNEL.SVRCONN"; // With  SSL
    MQEnvironment.port = XXXX;

    System.setProperty("javax.net.debug", "ssl");
    String cacerts="/opt/jdk1.8.0_121/jre/lib/security/cacerts";
    System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", cacerts);
    System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword", "changeit");
    MQEnvironment.sslCipherSuite = args[0];
    System.out.println("\t using ssl Cipher suite       :: " + MQEnvironment.sslCipherSuite);
    System.out.println("\t MQEnvironment.version_notice :: " + MQEnvironment.version_notice);
    MQEnvironment.properties.put(MQC.TRANSPORT_PROPERTY, MQC.TRANSPORT_MQSERIES);

    MQEnvironment.sslFipsRequired=false;
    _queueManager = new MQQueueManager("QUEUE_NAME");
  System.out.println("\t _queueManager                        : " + _queueManager);
  }
}
```

Debug Log :

```
/opt/ibm/java-i386-80/jre/bin/java -Dcom.ibm.jsse2.disableSSLv3=false   -jar MQ_Testing.jar TLS_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA 

         using ssl Cipher suite       :: TLS_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA

         MQEnvironment.version_notice :: Websphere MQ classes for Java V6.0.0

IBMJSSE2 will allow protocol SSLv3 per com.ibm.jsse2.disableSSLv3 set to FALSE

IBMJSSEProvider2 Build-Level: -20160616

Installed Providers =

        IBMJSSE2

        IBMJCE

        IBMJGSSProvider

        IBMCertPath

        IBMSASL

        IBMXMLCRYPTO

        IBMXMLEnc

        IBMSPNEGO

        SUN

jdk.tls.client.protocols is defined as null

SUPPORTED: [SSLv3, TLSv1, TLSv1.1, TLSv1.2]

SERVER_DEFAULT: [SSLv3, TLSv1, TLSv1.1, TLSv1.2]

CLIENT_DEFAULT: [SSLv3, TLSv1, TLSv1.1, TLSv1.2]

keyStore is: /opt/ibm/java-i386-80/jre/lib/security/cacerts

keyStore type is: jks

keyStore provider is:

init keystore

init keymanager of type IbmX509

trustStore is: /opt/jdk1.8.0_121/jre/lib/security/cacerts

trustStore type is: jks

trustStore provider is:

init truststore

adding as trusted cert:

  Subject: CN=Equifax Secure Global eBusiness CA-1, O=Equifax Secure Inc., C=US

  Issuer:  CN=Equifax Secure Global eBusiness CA-1, O=Equifax Secure Inc., C=US

  Algorithm: RSA; Serial number: 0xc3517

  Valid from Mon Jun 21 09:30:00 IST 1999 until Mon Jun 22 09:30:00 IST 2020

adding as trusted cert:

  Subject: CN=GeoTrust Primary Certification Authority - G2, OU=(c) 2007 
GeoTrust Inc. - For authorized use only, O=GeoTrust Inc., C=US
  Issuer:  CN=GeoTrust Primary Certification Authority - G2, OU=(c) 2007 
GeoTrust Inc. - For authorized use only, O=GeoTrust Inc., C=US

  Algorithm: EC; Serial number: 0x3cb2f4480a00e2feeb243b5e603ec36b

  Valid from Mon Nov 05 05:30:00 IST 2007 until Tue Jan 19 05:29:59 IST 2038

------

------

-------



our certificate info



---

-----

------

adding as trusted cert:

  Subject: CN=DigiCert Global Root G2, OU=www.digicert.com, O=DigiCert Inc, C=US

  Issuer:  CN=DigiCert Global Root G2, OU=www.digicert.com, O=DigiCert Inc, C=US

  Algorithm: RSA; Serial number: 0x33af1e6a711a9a0bb2864b11d09fae5

  Valid from Thu Aug 01 17:30:00 IST 2013 until Fri Jan 15 17:30:00 IST 2038

SSLContextImpl:  Using X509ExtendedKeyManager com.ibm.jsse2.aw

SSLContextImpl:  Using X509TrustManager com.ibm.jsse2.aA

JsseJCE:  Using SecureRandom IBMSecureRandom from provider IBMJCE version 1.8
trigger seeding of SecureRandom

done seeding SecureRandom

IBMJSSE2 will enable CBC protection

JsseJCE:  Using SecureRandom IBMSecureRandom from provider IBMJCE version 1.8

JsseJCE:  Using KeyAgreement ECDH from provider IBMJCE version 1.8

JsseJCE:  Using signature SHA1withECDSA from provider TBD via init

JsseJCE:  Using signature NONEwithECDSA from provider TBD via init

JsseJCE:  Using KeyFactory EC from provider IBMJCE version 1.8

JsseJCE:  Using KeyPairGenerator EC from provider TBD via init

JsseJce:  EC is available

IBMJSSE2 will allow RFC 5746 renegotiation per com.ibm.jsse2.renegotiate set to none or default

IBMJSSE2 will not require renegotiation indicator during initial handshake 
per com.ibm.jsse2.renegotiation.indicator set to OPTIONAL or default taken

IBMJSSE2 will not perform identity checking against the peer cert check during renegotiation per com.ibm.jsse2.renegotiation.peer.cert.check set to OFF or default

IBMJSSE2 will allow client initiated renegotiation per jdk.tls.rejectClientInitiatedRenegotiation set to FALSE or default

IBMJSSE2 will not allow unsafe server certificate change during renegotiation per jdk.tls.allowUnsafeServerCertChange set to FALSE or default

Is initial handshake: true

%% No cached client session

*** ClientHello, TLSv1

RandomCookie:  GMT: 1473994730 bytes = { 238, 137, 89, 128, 139, 82, 93, 119, 12, 104, 3, 150, 104, 218, 146, 252, 106, 230, 104, 227, 220, 195, 133, 177, 224, 70, 52, 127 }

Session ID:  {}

Cipher Suites: [SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA]

Compression Methods:  { 0 }

Extension renegotiation_info, ri_length: 0, ri_connection_data: { null }
***

main, WRITE: TLSv1 Handshake, length = 52

main, READ: TLSv1 Handshake, length = 856

*** ServerHello, TLSv1

RandomCookie:  GMT: 0 bytes = { 236, 88, 151, 94, 111, 9, 167, 185, 94, 81, 181, 148, 189, 136, 212, 113, 209, 109, 13, 193, 221, 127, 237, 75, 111, 58, 203, 130 }

Session ID:  {75, 215, 26, 41, 91, 78, 235, 37, 238, 153, 145, 133, 191, 24, 212, 43, 48, 183, 29, 255, 224, 52, 234, 162, 108, 152, 170, 224, 17, 94, 63, 154}

Cipher Suite: SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA

Compression Method: 0

Extension renegotiation_info, ri_length: 0, ri_connection_data: { null }
***

JsseJCE:  Using MessageDigest MD5 from provider IBMJCE version 1.8

JsseJCE:  Using MessageDigest SHA from provider IBMJCE version 1.8

%% Initialized:  [Session-1, SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA]

** SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA

*** Certificate chain

chain [0] = [

[

  Version: V3

  Subject: CN="XXX, O=XXX, OU=VIL, C=IN"

  Signature Algorithm: SHA1withRSA, OID = 1.2.840.113549.1.1.5

  Key:  IBMJCE RSA Public Key:

modulus:

29520274597059884884525162797844309564564740860314317076363623205590330620665285960098203994430649948452267736624734060083888254808645851791784899893187301774015459836549786877052861001494184226379092315448710377951407842057987341460256107051853392995727416012224181106667030239052484951915573460835538842193183692008554795370126435248099845779739150211076745709763656203626931710137691863377966754291466123511621939080200053832041159491199213401094161487450139611524627709969107242299349846233668554767700637296506799788156861380576834589242935902127652273390577803901208287815787363344752279450721968318806451327069

public exponent:

65537

  Validity: [From: Tue Jan 17 12:36:21 IST 2017,

               To: Sat Jan 13 12:36:21 IST 2018]

  Issuer: CN="XXX, O=XXX, OU=VIL, C=IN"

  SerialNumber: [1251192874879434500]

]

  Algorithm: [SHA1withRSA]

  Signature:

0000: 9c 7c 69 77 7b 26 59 e0  d3 10 0c d8 ae 10 b8 29  ..iw..Y.........
0010: 3d a8 3e 63 e5 e0 49 aa  73 71 14 68 a1 5e a8 c3  ...c..I.sq.h....
0020: 8e 55 ca f2 2f b2 21 00  c9 ac 6f 6e 9a 36 6a 39  .U........on.6j9
0030: 51 68 62 e5 23 e6 49 4a  8f d0 f5 25 16 a0 37 d5  Qhb...IJ......7.
0040: a4 99 ed c4 84 73 61 23  88 76 e7 d4 8e 1b d9 f0  .....sa..v......
0050: dd b8 e1 8f 21 c3 92 d7  8f b0 3c cc 42 98 17 50  ............B..P
0060: db 09 27 f9 1f 8b c1 29  68 e4 66 00 e2 9e b2 d3  ........h.f.....
0070: bd 98 8e 95 00 80 eb d1  3b cf 24 1a 86 ad 35 67  ..............5g
0080: 59 3a 3f e0 20 e7 f0 94  c6 4a 0c 5c 1a de 2b 22  Y........J......
0090: 6f 1c cb 23 08 55 1c 61  72 29 14 d8 7c 7b bf 31  o....U.ar......1
00a0: 0d d3 0a 38 e1 98 af 65  e5 7d 0f 9c d5 a5 3f 00  ...8...e........
00b0: f4 b1 dd 89 89 9b 57 42  46 80 a5 7e 30 62 bd cf  ......WBF...0b..
00c0: d5 4b d1 33 df 10 55 ac  3a 46 6e d0 e6 df 7c 35  .K.3..U..Fn....5
00d0: b1 c2 81 ef d0 7b 6d f3  cc ff d1 ea 40 9f 6e 6c  ......m.......nl
00e0: 5d c6 8f 45 2a dd 7a 9d  47 de b4 6c 33 0d cf 51  ...E..z.G..l3..Q
00f0: ad 68 54 aa 35 77 39 ed  4b 90 6e ee 46 f3 e0 81  .hT.5w9.K.n.F...
]

***

Found trusted certificate:

[

[

  Version: V3

  Subject: CN="XXX, O=XXX, OU=VIL, C=IN"

  Signature Algorithm: SHA1withRSA, OID = 1.2.840.113549.1.1.5

  Key:  IBMJCE RSA Public Key:

modulus:

29520274597059884884525162797844309564564740860314317076363623205590330620665285960098203994430649948452267736624734060083888254808645851791784899893187301774015459836549786877052861001494184226379092315448710377951407842057987341460256107051853392995727416012224181106667030239052484951915573460835538842193183692008554795370126435248099845779739150211076745709763656203626931710137691863377966754291466123511621939080200053832041159491199213401094161487450139611524627709969107242299349846233668554767700637296506799788156861380576834589242935902127652273390577803901208287815787363344752279450721968318806451327069

public exponent:

65537

  Validity: [From: Tue Jan 17 12:36:21 IST 2017,

               To: Sat Jan 13 12:36:21 IST 2018]

  Issuer: CN="XXX, O=XXX, OU=VIL, C=IN"

  SerialNumber: [1251192874879434500]

]

  Algorithm: [SHA1withRSA]

  Signature:

0000: 9c 7c 69 77 7b 26 59 e0  d3 10 0c d8 ae 10 b8 29  ..iw..Y.........
0010: 3d a8 3e 63 e5 e0 49 aa  73 71 14 68 a1 5e a8 c3  ...c..I.sq.h....
0020: 8e 55 ca f2 2f b2 21 00  c9 ac 6f 6e 9a 36 6a 39  .U........on.6j9
0030: 51 68 62 e5 23 e6 49 4a  8f d0 f5 25 16 a0 37 d5  Qhb...IJ......7.
0040: a4 99 ed c4 84 73 61 23  88 76 e7 d4 8e 1b d9 f0  .....sa..v......
0050: dd b8 e1 8f 21 c3 92 d7  8f b0 3c cc 42 98 17 50  ............B..P
0060: db 09 27 f9 1f 8b c1 29  68 e4 66 00 e2 9e b2 d3  ........h.f.....
0070: bd 98 8e 95 00 80 eb d1  3b cf 24 1a 86 ad 35 67  ..............5g
0080: 59 3a 3f e0 20 e7 f0 94  c6 4a 0c 5c 1a de 2b 22  Y........J......
0090: 6f 1c cb 23 08 55 1c 61  72 29 14 d8 7c 7b bf 31  o....U.ar......1
00a0: 0d d3 0a 38 e1 98 af 65  e5 7d 0f 9c d5 a5 3f 00  ...8...e........
00b0: f4 b1 dd 89 89 9b 57 42  46 80 a5 7e 30 62 bd cf  ......WBF...0b..
00c0: d5 4b d1 33 df 10 55 ac  3a 46 6e d0 e6 df 7c 35  .K.3..U..Fn....5
00d0: b1 c2 81 ef d0 7b 6d f3  cc ff d1 ea 40 9f 6e 6c  ......m.......nl
00e0: 5d c6 8f 45 2a dd 7a 9d  47 de b4 6c 33 0d cf 51  ...E..z.G..l3..Q
00f0: ad 68 54 aa 35 77 39 ed  4b 90 6e ee 46 f3 e0 81  .hT.5w9.K.n.F...
]

*** CertificateRequest

Cert Types: RSA

Cert Authorities:



*** ServerHelloDone

ClientHandshaker: KeyManager com.ibm.jsse2.aw

*** Certificate chain

***

JsseJCE:  Using KeyGenerator IbmTlsRsaPremasterSecret from provider TBD via init

JsseJCE:  Using cipher RSA/SSL/PKCS1Padding from provider TBD via init

PreMasterSecret:  Using cipher for wrap RSA/SSL/PKCS1Padding from provider from init IBMJCE version 1.8

*** ClientKeyExchange, RSA PreMasterSecret, TLSv1

main, WRITE: TLSv1 Handshake, length = 269

SESSION KEYGEN:

PreMaster Secret:

0000: 03 01 ca e5 e2 4f f5 ba  fc e5 ef e7 f0 ce 11 41  .....O.........A
0010: 1c 4f 8e b0 8b b0 1e 0f  25 96 85 a4 18 64 f4 22  .O...........d..
0020: ba 99 3c b2 08 64 b0 c0  0a 72 09 23 fe e8 67 48  .....d...r....gH

javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec@13e668a

JsseJCE: Choose KeyGenerator for IbmTlsMasterSecret.

JsseJCE:  Using KeyGenerator IbmTlsMasterSecret from provider TBD via init

JsseJCE:  Using KeyGenerator IbmTlsKeyMaterial from provider TBD via init

CONNECTION KEYGEN:

Client Nonce:

0000: 58 db 60 ea ee 89 59 80  8b 52 5d 77 0c 68 03 96  X.....Y..R.w.h..
0010: 68 da 92 fc 6a e6 68 e3  dc c3 85 b1 e0 46 34 7f  h...j.h......F4.

Server Nonce:

0000: 00 00 00 00 ec 58 97 5e  6f 09 a7 b9 5e 51 b5 94  .....X..o....Q..
0010: bd 88 d4 71 d1 6d 0d c1  dd 7f ed 4b 6f 3a cb 82  ...q.m.....Ko...

Master Secret:

0000: 0a ca f1 d7 05 94 2e 07  1d 2a 27 bb e9 6a a2 dd  .............j..
0010: a1 70 32 ee 4c da 20 df  c2 95 aa bd 2c e9 cd 02  .p2.L...........
0020: 6b c7 17 9d bc 02 1f 22  31 a7 9b 78 ce 42 5b cf  k.......1..x.B..

Client MAC write Secret:

0000: 5f 22 6c 73 aa 0c 89 b5  8c 55 f4 c2 2c 67 6a 83  ..ls.....U...gj.
0010: 56 c4 00 c6            
                            V...
Server MAC write Secret:

0000: 3e d4 16 07 87 f4 75 73  bc 76 6a 78 2c 3e b5 3a  ......us.vjx....
0010: 4e 45 ad e9            
                            NE..
Client write key:

0000: cd d0 2d 55 ca a3 62 92  78 13 a4 2d 9c 3a 79 a9  ...U..b.x.....y.
0010: 5b 3f 03 97 06 33 3d ff                           .....3..

Server write key:

0000: e1 e8 89 c1 85 f5 09 32  25 75 19 dd 62 7a b2 c9  .......2.u..bz..
0010: 7f 63 ab 28 2d 6d 5d 45                           .c...m.E

Client write IV:

0000: db 7f 8f 71 11 c5 1e b3                           ...q....
Server write IV:

0000: 9c 74 e2 ae d6 62 56 3f                           .t...bV.

JsseJCE:  Using KeyGenerator IbmTlsPrf from provider TBD via init

HandshakeMessage:  TLS Keygenerator IbmTlsPrf  from provider from init IBMJCE version 1.8

main, WRITE: TLSv1 Change Cipher Spec, length = 1

JsseJCE:  Using cipher DESede/CBC/NoPadding from provider TBD via init

CipherBox:  Using cipher DESede/CBC/NoPadding from provider from init IBMJCE 
version 1.8
JsseJCE:  Using MAC HmacSHA1 from provider TBD via init

MAC:  Using MessageDigest HmacSHA1 from provider IBMJCE version 1.8

*** Finished

verify_data:  { 194, 19, 125, 188, 103, 19, 170, 48, 12, 172, 132, 24 }
***

main, WRITE: TLSv1 Handshake, length = 40

main, READ: TLSv1 Change Cipher Spec, length = 1

JsseJCE:  Using cipher DESede/CBC/NoPadding from provider TBD via init

CipherBox:  Using cipher DESede/CBC/NoPadding from provider from init IBMJCE 
version 1.8

JsseJCE:  Using MAC HmacSHA1 from provider TBD via init

MAC:  Using MessageDigest HmacSHA1 from provider IBMJCE version 1.8

main, READ: TLSv1 Handshake, length = 40

*** Finished

verify_data:  { 0, 3, 116, 83, 135, 81, 160, 25, 151, 242, 17, 213 }

***

JsseJCE:  Using KeyGenerator IbmTlsPrf from provider TBD via init

HandshakeMessage:  TLS Keygenerator IbmTlsPrf  from provider from init IBMJCE version 1.8

%% Cached client session: [Session-1, SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA]

main, setSoTimeout(120000) called

main, WRITE: TLSv1 Application Data, length = 184

main, READ: TLSv1 Application Data, length = 64

main, WRITE: TLSv1 Application Data, length = 24

main, WRITE: TLSv1 Application Data, length = 48

main, called close()

main, called closeInternal(true)

main, SEND TLSv1 ALERT:  warning, description = close_notify

main, WRITE: TLSv1 Alert, length = 24

main, called closeSocket(true)

MQJE001: An MQException occurred: Completion Code 2, Reason 2009

MQJE016: MQ queue manager closed channel immediately during connect
Closure reason = 2009

MQJE001: An MQException occurred: Completion Code 2, Reason 2009

MQJE016: MQ queue manager closed channel immediately during connect
Closure reason = 2009

Exception in thread "main" com.ibm.mq.MQException: MQJE001: An MQException occurred: Completion Code 2, Reason 2009

MQJE016: MQ queue manager closed channel immediately during connect
Closure reason = 2009

        at com.ibm.mq.MQManagedConnectionJ11.(MQManagedConnectionJ11.java:212)

        at com.ibm.mq.MQClientManagedConnectionFactoryJ11._createManagedConnection(MQClientManagedConnectionFactoryJ11.java:318)

        at com.ibm.mq.MQClientManagedConnectionFactoryJ11.createManagedConnection(MQClientManagedConnectionFactoryJ11.java:338)

        at com.ibm.mq.StoredManagedConnection.(StoredManagedConnection.java:84)

        at com.ibm.mq.MQSimpleConnectionManager.allocateConnection(MQSimpleConnectionManager.java:168)

        at com.ibm.mq.MQQueueManagerFactory.obtainBaseMQQueueManager(MQQueueManagerFactory.java:772)

        at com.ibm.mq.MQQueueManagerFactory.procure(MQQueueManagerFactory.java:697)

        at com.ibm.mq.MQQueueManagerFactory.constructQueueManager(MQQueueManagerFactory.java:657)

        at com.ibm.mq.MQQueueManagerFactory.createQueueManager(MQQueueManagerFactory.java:153)

        at com.ibm.mq.MQQueueManager.(MQQueueManager.java:451)

        at com.apalya.main.MQTest.main(MQTest.java:129)

Caused by: com.ibm.mqservices.MQInternalException: MQJE001: An MQException occurred: Completion Code 2, Reason 2009

MQJE016: MQ queue manager closed channel immediately during connect
Closure reason = 2009

        at com.ibm.mq.MQv6InternalCommunications.checkControlFlags(MQv6InternalCommunications.java:740)

        at com.ibm.mq.MQv6InternalCommunications.establishChannel(MQv6InternalCommunications.java:656)

        at com.ibm.mq.MQv6InternalCommunications.initialize(MQv6InternalCommunications.java:206)

        at com.ibm.mq.MQv6InternalCommunications.(MQv6InternalCommunications.java:102)

        at com.ibm.mq.MQSESSIONClient.MQCONNX(MQSESSIONClient.java:1337)

        at com.ibm.mq.MQSESSIONClient.MQCONN(MQSESSIONClient.java:1246)

        at com.ibm.mq.MQManagedConnectionJ11.(MQManagedConnectionJ11.java:184)

        ... 10 more
```

Can anyone please help/suggest on this

Comment: Please provide the full version of MQ for the MQ Server as well as for the jar files used by the client application.

Comment: Please provide the error observed in the MQ Queue manager log files at the time you observe this error.  It does appear you are using MQ v6.0 jar files which have been out of support from IBM since September 30 2012, and may not work with Java 8.  Newer MQ client versions can connect to older MQ queue managers.  You can download a java only install of [IBM MQ v8.0 Client](http://www.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg24037500) or  [IBM MQ v9.0 Client](http://www.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg24042176) jar files.